# How to find filesystem type without read permission? Somehow gnome-disks can

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I get a permission error trying to find the filesystem type of a block device:

```
$ file -s /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1: no read permission
```

However, If I open gnome-disks, it will happily tell me info all the info about /dev/sdd1 that I want. I checked that gnome-disks is running as my user which does not have read access to /dev/sdd1. So my question is:

How can I find the filesystem type of /dev/sdd1 without read permission to the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
udisksctl info -b /dev/sdd1
```

correctly identifies the system as crypto_LUKS.

Answer (score 0):

The `df` command can give you that info.

`df -T /dev/sdd1`